# Is the API readonly right now?

Tags: support

Does the StackOverflow API offer some way to authenticate a user?
I am wondering if the API supports logging a user in so that they can write to the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is [read-only](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-exchange-api-public-beta-starts/), you can't authenticate a user in any way.

> Version 1 is read only. Coming up with
>   a solid API is hard enough without
>   adding writing and authentication to
>   the mix. For the initial release, it’s
>   a read-only API. We’ll take on the
>   much more challenging problem of
>   writing (and authentication) in v2.

Comment: a v1.5 would be nice, without write access.

Comment: @Jonathan - I'm curious what you feel is missing in the 1.0 version? Seems to work really well for me.

Comment: @scunliffe, there a few thongs I've come across, I cant think of all of them offs the top of my head, but the main thing I'd like is global inbox, all of the information it provides is available through the API but would require wayyy too many requests. And a numerical ID for each site would be useful.